# OpenVPN Connect to Internet Issue

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

I currently trying to set up OpenVPN server on Ubuntu Server 16.04. I followed guide provided by DigitalOcean and made the necessary settings but when i connect my OpenVPN server via It's Windows client it works well but seems like have trouble with connecting to the internet. Here is my openvpn settings file;

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
key-direction 0
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

And client config;

```
    client
;dev tap
dev tun
;dev-node MyTap
proto udp
remote SERVER-IP-HERE 1194
;remote-random
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]
;mute-replay-warnings
;ca ca.crt
;cert client.crt
;key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
;tls-auth ta.key 1
;cipher x
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
key-direction 1
comp-lzo
verb 3
;mute 20

#REST OF FIE CONTAINS CA INFORMATION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured your VPN server to route all traffic through the VPN server itself, is that on purpose?

I'd try removing the following directive:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Then restart openvpn server service and retry.

**Edit #1:**

If that's the case, then add the following directive to the server conf:

```
push "remote-gateway vpn_server_ip"
```

And restart the service.

This will push the gateway address to the vpn clients.

**Edit #2:**

Run the following command on your openvpn server:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Add the following to your server configuration:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
```

Restart the service and retry.

Comment: Yes this is main purpose to set-up VPN server. I want to tunnel all my traffic over the VPN.

Comment: I put my server's external IP address at vpn_server_ip and restart the service but still same. Only able to connect server itself.

Comment: You need to use the OpenVPN server's internal ip, the one in the openvpn network - 10.8.0.1 if I'm not mistaken - but check it in the server itself.

Comment: Changed the config file as you pointed but still cannot connect anywhere outside server itself.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I got no errors. Just cannot connect anywhere outside the server while VPN client is on.

Comment: Please check Edit #2

Comment: I made the changes and its now working. Seems like this were the missing part. Thank you for assistance.

Comment: Cannot upvote because my reputation but accepted as answer. Thanks :)